# Assigning JavaScript variable to PHP variable on same page

Tags: javascript, php

i have two drop downs the second one will be populated based on the value selected in the first drop down.I am able to populate the first dropdown from database. to populate the second dropdown list i am firing a select query through recordset.but i am not able to achieve my goal.Here is my code

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/finalkms.php'); 


mysql_select_db($database_finalkms, $finalkms);
$query_getzones = "SELECT distinct Zone FROM asset";
$getzones = mysql_query($query_getzones, $finalkms) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getzones = mysql_fetch_assoc($getzones);
$totalRows_getzones = mysql_num_rows($getzones);

$zone=$_GET['zonehide'];

$query_getcountry = "SELECT distinct CountryCode FROM asset where Zone='.$zone.'";
$getcountry = mysql_query($query_getcountry, $finalkms) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getcountry = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcountry);
$totalRows_getcountry = mysql_num_rows($getcountry);

?>

<script>

function getgraphs()
{
    var zone=document.getElementById('zone').value;
    document.getElementById('zonehide').value=zone;
    alert(zone);
    if(zone == 'SEA')
    {
        alert("hello");
        document.getElementById('countrysea').display='block';

    }


}

</script>


<input name="hdn" id="zonehide" type="hidden" value="<?php echo "<script>document.getElementById('zonehide').value;</script>";?>"/>
Zone:<select id="zone" onChange="getgraphs()">
<?php do { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_getzones['Zone']; ?>"><?php echo $row_getzones['Zone']; ?></option>
 <?php } while ($row_getzones = mysql_fetch_assoc($getzones)); ?>
</select>

Country:<select id="countrysea">

<?php do { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_getcountry['CountryCode']; ?>"><?php echo $row_getcountry['CountryCode']; ?></option>
 <?php } while ($row_getcountry = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcountry)); ?>
</select>

</select>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between client-side and server-side code. PHP is executed on the server. JavaScript is executed on the client.

Comment: PHP is just run once when the page is retrieved. It is not persistent. Javascript runs on the client and is persistent.

Comment: First of all you have a SQL injection risk there. Someone could mess up or steal your database by setting the zone GET variable. Use the [mysqli](http://us1.php.net/mysqli) extension with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Php is a server side language, where as JavaScript is client side. In order to pass from JavaScript to php, you need to use AJAX calls to a standalone php file.

Create your menu populating functions in menu.php, and have JavaScript/jquery send an AJAX call to that php file to populate the HTML menus.